# What's the correct regular expression that I need?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to search and replace in a string using php's `preg_replace` in relative large text.

Search: `[3,Name]`
Replace: `<a href="/Name/3/">Name</a>`

Could somebody help me building the right query?

Thanks.

Comment: so the input is `[3,Name]` and you want that to print `<a href="/Name/3/">Name</a>`?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like:

```
#\[(\d+),(\w+)\]#i
```

So the result would be something like:

```
preg_replace('#\[(\d+),(\w+)\]#i', '<a href="/$2/$1/">$2</a>', $text);
```

Comment: @jeroen: Maybe you should take the numbers as in **3:** [in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13279124/367456)

Comment: @hakre Ouch, switched the variables around...

Answer (score 2):

Help building your query:

```
 0: [3,Name]

 1: "[" "3" "," "Name" "]"
     1   2   3    4     5

 2: "[" \d+ ","   \w+  "]"
         1         2           

 3: "<a href=\"" 2 "/" 1 "/\">" 2 "</a>

 4: "<a href=\"Name/3/\">Name</a>"
```

If you want to create a regular expression, you need to find your pattern first.

Comment: Sure I need to learn, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `explode()`:

```
$string='[3,Name]';
$string=str_replace(array(']','['),array('',''),$string);//remove the brackets
$array= explode(',',$string);
echo '<a href="/'.$array[1].'/'.$array[0].'/">'.$array[1].'</a>'
```

Maybe do some error checking depending on the variability of your input.

Comment: This will not work in a large string with my needle in the middle.